# Another inequality about $\frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{c+a} + \frac{c}{a+b}$

Tags: inequality

$a,b,c > 0, a^{\frac{3}{2}} + b^{\frac{3}{2}} + c^{\frac{3}{2}}=1$, prove:
$\dfrac{a}{b+c} + \dfrac{b}{c+a} + \dfrac{c}{a+b} \le \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{abc}}$

Context:

Got from social media -- wechat group

People in wechat group: casual friends -- normal people around 30 to 50 years old, around the world

Similar questions: search on inequalities list in wiki

Here is what I tried:

$$
\begin{multline}
\shoveleft \text{Let } x=a^{\frac{1}{2}},y=b^{\frac{1}{2}},z=c^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
\shoveleft \implies x^3+y^3+z^3=1\\
\shoveleft \sqrt[3]{x^3y^3z^3}=xyz\le\dfrac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{3}=\dfrac{1}{3}\\
\shoveleft \dfrac{a}{b+c} + \dfrac{b}{c+a} + \dfrac{c}{a+b} \\
\shoveleft = \dfrac{x^2}{y^2+z^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{z^2+x^2} + \dfrac{z^2}{x^2+y^2} \\
\shoveleft = (x^2+y^2+z^2)(\dfrac{1}{y^2+z^2} + \dfrac{1}{z^2+x^2} + \dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2})-3 \\
\shoveleft \le (x^2+y^2+z^2)(\dfrac{1}{2yz}+\dfrac{1}{2zx}+\dfrac{1}{2xy})-3\\
\shoveleft =\dfrac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x+y+z)-6xyz}{2xyz}\\
\end{multline}
$$
So we need prove $(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x+y+z) < 1+6xyz$

or equivatently $xy(x+y)+yz(y+z)+xz(z+x) \le 6xyz$

or equivatently $(x+y+z)(xy+xz+xy) \le 9xyz$

Update: Solved with RiverLi's comment.

Comment: Have you tried lagrange multiplier to maximize the LHS?

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 That would make the format very complicated when seeking derivation... you can try and know.

Comment: Missing context : kindly provide a source for this question (not expecting it to be from an ongoing competition, but in any case). Also mention and link any similar questions on this site (or elsewhere) that you may have solved. Thanks.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Added context: Context: got from social media -- wechat group. People in wechat group: casual friends -- normal people around 30 to 50 years old, around the world; Similar questions: search on inequalities list in wiki

Comment: Thank you very much for your response to my comment. I was hoping for something more mathematical from your source, but I will leave anything else to the inequality experts to decide. Actually, I'll first look for a duplicate.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer No I seek for any kind of math puzzles or problems on social media and try to work on them. There are lots of problems on Twitter, or even Instagram, or telegram channels. Nobody asks for source of problems on twitter, if you have questions or solutions, just reply or retweet. No security check...

Comment: @rne I understand, I am asking for a source because [math.SE question guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) behoove me to ensure that every question is provided with context. It is a hard-and-fast rule, to some extent. Nevertheless, I'll leave you with [this link](https://approach0.xyz/), which is a search engine that can help you find similar inequalities. For example, if you need to see how to start working from $a^{\frac{3}{2}} 
+ b^{\frac 32} + c^{\frac 32} = 1$, some substitutions can be found by searching for that here.

Comment: I haven't voted to close this question, in case you were wondering. But two other people did, and they did so because context was missing. My only aim is to ensure that this question stays afloat through provision of context, which was done to my satisfaction. Thanks.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Yes I understand there is a hard-and-fast rule on this site, so I need to be honest and frank that there ARE MANY math problems and puzzles floating around in the air of social media with no academic contexts. So I do think that this IS a category of source to be considered by this site.

Comment: @rne Exactly : that's why I'm not complaining. The basic idea of asking for a source for a contest-question is to make sure that it isn't an ongoing contest, really. There is some more stuff, but I wanted to make sure of that much, and am fairly convinced. I understand that social media is a source, the only problem is that it isn't a "mathematical" one i.e. provides  no standard tools by itself in solving such questions. Then again, one can do nothing much about that, so I suggested other things, which have been done somewhat anyway. I'll now leave the inequality experts to decide things.

Comment: @rne Use AM-GM: $\frac{a}{b+c} \le \frac{a}{2\sqrt{bc}}$.

Comment: @RiverLi Oh yes, i applied this later... should do it in original equation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{abc}}$.

we know that$(x+y)\geq 2\sqrt{xy}$ so $\frac{1}{x+y}\leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{xy}}$,applying the same for all terms, we will obtain $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}\leq \frac{a}{2\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{ac}}+\frac{c}{2\sqrt{ab}}$,

so it is enough to prove  that $\frac{a}{2\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{ac}}+\frac{c}{2\sqrt{ab}} \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{abc}}$.

$\frac{a}{2\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{ac}}+\frac{c}{2\sqrt{ab}}=\frac{a\sqrt{a}+b\sqrt{b}+c\sqrt{c}}{2\sqrt{abc}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{abc}} $(because ( $x\sqrt{x}=x^{\frac{3}{2}})$.

so we finally;
$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b} \leq \frac{a}{2\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{ac}}+\frac{c}{2\sqrt{ab}}= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{abc}}$.